# How to loop through an array and replacing some of its values?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, replace

I have now the following code:

```
shp = this.getField("shp");
out = this.getField("txt")
p = shp.value.split("");
pn = "";

for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) { 
    pn += p[i].charCodeAt(0);
};
```

Now I want to **loop through pn** and **check for values greater than 56**,

these values I want to **replace with (the value - 63)%10**

how can I do that?

So, to be a little bit clearer:

I want to rewrite the following vba code to run it on adobe acrobat:

```
Function upsp(number)
qsm = 0
For i = 1 To 15
p = Mid(number, i, 1)
If Asc(p) > 57 Then p = (Asc(p) - 63) Mod 10
qsm = qsm + (p * (2 - i Mod 2))
Next
upsp = 10 - (qsm Mod 10)
If upsp = 10 Then upsp = 0
End Function
```

this code calculate a checksum for a ups tracking number.

Comment: You have your loop. Now parse, compare, and replace. What are you having trouble with exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shp = this.getField("shp");
out = this.getField("txt")
p = shp.value.split("");
pn = "";

for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) { 
    // pn += p[i].charCodeAt(0);
    if (p[i]>56) p[i] = (p[i] - 63)%10; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not your code but with

```
for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) { 
  if(p[i].charCodeAt(0) > 56) pn += (p[i].charCodeAt(0) -63)%10;//do you want 10 percent or modulus of 10? %10 will be the modulus /10 woul be 10 percent
  else
  pn += p[i].charCodeAt(0);
};
```

If it's not what you're looking for you should rephrase the question, because I honestly didn't get it.

Comment: ps.: why are you using charcodeat()? Stating what you're trying to accomplish might help us answering. :)